# react-native-camera default Camera UI

Tags: react-native, camera, react-native-camera

When using react-native-camera to allow photo capture; is there an API to simply enable the default platform camera UI, or an additional library? I've been looking for this for a while with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

let try this lib [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker).
Its use default Camera.